# Laravel Nova Metric displaying data from other metric

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a two Nova Trend metrics called `ApiCallsPerHour` and `ApiCallsPerMinute`, each with a simple calculate function:

**ApiCallsPerHour**

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return $this->countByHours($request, ApiCall::class);
}
```

**ApiCallsPerMinute**

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return $this->countByMinutes($request, ApiCall::class);
}
```

The problem is the `ApiCallsByMinute` trend displays always displays the trend by hours.

I have tested and both components are loaded correctly: if I change their `ranges` array they independently update from each other. But whatever I put in the `calculate` method in the `ApiCallsPerMinute`, it always displays the hourly trend, even if I put `return 100;`.

Only when I remove the `ApiCallsPerHour` trend from the dashboard, the `ApiCallsPerMinute` is displayed correctly.

Both components do not have a value returned in the `cacheFor` method.

Answer (score 0):

It was clear I was missing something big... These components had the same `uriKey` ‍♂️. Don't copy paste your components folks, use the `php artisan nova:trend` command!